# Set infinispan entity cache eviction and expiration policies via cli console

Tags: jboss, infinispan, jboss-cli

I need to add some cli command to change my infinispan entity settings from

```
<invalidation-cache name="entity" mode="SYNC">
    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
</invalidation-cache>
```

to

```
<invalidation-cache name="entity" mode="ASYNC">
    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
    <expiration lifespan="100000"/>
</invalidation-cache>
```

For now I have two commands that removing existing setting and creates a new one but without specify eviction and expiration policies.

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=hibernate/invalidation-cache=entity:remove
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=hibernate/invalidation-cache=entity:add(mode=ASYNC)
```

how can I specify eviction and expiration policies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CLI command which changes only the attribute value:

```
/profile=full-ha/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=hibernate/invalidation-cache=entity:write-attribute(name=mode, value=ASYNC)
```